# GSON TypeAdapter not being called during deserialization of an array

Tags: android, json, gson, json-deserialization

Because Gson uses reflection to build objects during deserialization via a no-arguments constructor, I am writing a `TypeAdapter` that will instead use the appropriate constructor for my object. I need this to happen because the object I am deserializing is a subclass of another and needs to call the super constructor appropriately.

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON array that looks something like this (this is example data, not the actual structure of my object):

```
[
    {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "description": "...",
        "others": [
            {
                "key1": "val",
                "key2": "val"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "...",
        "name": "...",
        "description": "...",
        "others": [
            {
                "key1": "val",
                "key2": "val"
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

But I want to use a `TypeAdapter` during the deserialization of the objects that comprise this array. To be clear, this is how I am initiating the Gson deserialization:

```
new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(new TypeToken<MyObject>() {}.getType(), new MyTypeAdapter())
    .create()
    .fromJson(inputJson, MyObject[].class);
```

And this is `MyTypeAdapter`:

```
class MyTypeAdapter : TypeAdapter<MyObject> {
    private val type = object : TypeToken<MyObject>() {}.type

    override fun write(out: JsonWriter, myObject: MyObject) {
        Gson().toJson(myObject, type, out))
    }

    override fun read(in: JsonReader): MyObject {
        Log.d("MyTypeAdapter", "Deserialization via custom TypeAdapter")
        val objByReflection = new Gson().fromJson(in, type)
        return MyObject(objByReflection.id, objByReflection.name, objByReflection.description, objByReflection.others)
    }
}
```

However, I find that the TypeAdapter is not used for the deserialization; setting a breakpoint doesn't find it being hit, and I get no log output.

Is this happening because I am actually deserializing an array of `MyObject`? What would be a good way to remedy this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using it with retrofit rest client?

Comment: Yes I am using it with the retrofit rest client

Comment: can you post the code that build retrofit instance